# S3 Bucket - Move File Rather Than Delete When Doing sync

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, synchronization

aws has the s3 sync option, which has the delete option. So running something like:

aws --delete s3 sync /files/ s3://files/

Would delete all the files from s3://files/ that have been deleted from /files/ on the local server. I don't want to delete things from s3://files/ I want to move them to another bucket.

What I'd like to do is something more like a MOVE than a DELETE. Move out of one bucket into another if a file has been removed from the local server. So I first figure out what has been deleted from /files/ and then move that out of s3://files/ and into s3://deleted-files/

I know "s3 sync" has --dry-run, but it's not clear to me the most efficient way to do this. I can use just about anything to make it happen, though I'll be triggering this via cron.

Comment: I don't think this is directly possible.

Comment: As you mention you can use just about anything.... I'd create a list of local files at the end of the cron job.  Then next time the job runs, use diff + grep or awk to create a list of missing files, and then call the cli  for each file  to move it to a different bucket on S3.